# Trying to add a PDF stamp using iTextSharp, "The byte array is not a recognized imageformat"

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to add a stamp to a PDF, where the file for the stamp is itself a PDF.  Here's my code:

```
void addImage(string inputPath,string imagePath,string outputPath,int pageNumber)
{ 
    Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
    pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
}

void addImageTest()
{
    string sourceFile = @"C:\somefolder\source.pdf";
    string stampFile = @"C:\somefolder\stamp.pdf";
    string destFile = @"C:\somefolder\destination.pdf";
    addImage(sourceFile, stampFile, destFile, 1);
    return;
}
```

On the call to `GetInstance()`, I get this exception:

```
The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
```

Update: looking at [the source code for GetInstance()](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6/blob/master/iTextSharp/text/Image.cs), I see that it works with GIF, TIFF, JPEG, PNG, WMF, and BMP, but **not** PDF.  So I need to figure out another way to use a PDF as an image, I think.  Any ideas?

Comment: You were *not* looking at the official source of iTextSharp but that of a fork. The official source can be found at http://github.com/itext/itextsharp. Also, you are using a version that is several years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PDF is a document format, not an image format, hence `Image.GetInstance()` doesn't accept PDF bytes. That doesn't mean there is no workaround.

A PDF document can be read by the `PdfReader` object:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
```

You can reuse pages from the PDF that is being read by using the `PdfImportedPage` object:

```
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
```

In the line above, `writer` is the `PdfWriter` instance of the document you're creating. The `GetImportedPage` method copies resources needed for `page` to the new file. Resources could be fonts, images,...

`PdfImportedPage` extends `PdfTemplate`. `PdfTemplate` is the class used for *Form XObject*. Raster images are stored as external objects called *Image XObjects*. Vector data (e.g. WMF, an imported PDF page, a stream of PDF syntax) is stored as *Form XObjects*.

You now have two different options to add that `PdfTemplate` (or `PdfImportedPage`) named `page` to the document.

1. you can use the `AddTemplate()` method: `writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, x, y);`
2. you can wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object: `iTextSharp.text.Image Img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page);`

Note that, whichever option you choose, the PDF will never be converted to a raster image. It will be added as vector data.

**Update:**

In your case, you have to replace `writer` like this:

- `pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);`
- `pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber).AddTemplate(page, x, y);`

My examples were made in the case you create a PDF from scratch.

Comment: This does enable me to add a PDF, but I would really like to add it as a normal stamp, such that it can be selected, dragged around the page, and deleted.  This use of `AddTemplate()` seems to add it as static content--am I missing something?

Comment: You can use the template as the appearance of a stamp annotation. Let me know if this didn't work for you. See http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-printable-or-non-printable-bitmap-stamp-pdf

Comment: I'm following the itextpdf.com example, but `app.AddImage(stampImg)` is throwing the exception: `The image must have absolute positioning.`

Comment: Never mind, forgot the `SetAbsolutePosition(0,0)` call.  Works great!